How to add user's PATH to systemd service without hardcoding it?
I have a systemd service like so:
[Unit]
Description=description here
After=database.service

[Service]
Type=simple
User=user
WorkingDirectory=/home/user/project
ExecStart=/home/user/.local/share/pnpm/pnpm start
LoadCredentialEncrypted=a:/home/user/project/.credstore/a.cred
LoadCredentialEncrypted=b:/home/user/project/.credstore/b.cred
LoadCredentialEncrypted=c:/home/user/project/.credstore/c.cred
LoadCredentialEncrypted=d:/home/user/project/.credstore/d.cred

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

And when I try to start it, I get this error:
> project@0.1.0 start /home/user/project
> node .
sh: 1: node: not found
ELIFECYCLE  Command failed.

Which makes sense, the PATH env var is incomplete. I can printenv and copy the correct PATH env var into my service like so:
Environment=PATH=paste here

And that does work without any issues. But this means I now need to edit my service whenever the PATH env var changes, and I don't want that. Is there no better way to obtain the PATH env var from the user and attach it to the service?

Reading .bashrc at service start time:
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c ". ~/.bashrc ; exec /home/user/.local/share/pnpm/pnpm start"

This outputs the exact same error I included in the post, about node not being found.

@ElJay: What did you do so it's in your path when you log in then?

Whatever pnpm does by default I guess. Copy pasting the output of printenv PATH into the service file does work in case that wasn't clear. I just don't want to hardcode it like that.

@ElJay: This is now a research project; search your .dot files for that individual path component.

It's added at the end of my .bashrc file, so seems that your command isn't working.

@ElJay: There is something you're not telling me.

I'm not sure what that would be. There's a snippet where pnpm is added to the PATH at the end of the user's .bashrc file, and when I put in your ExecStart line it errors, unable to find the node command. I'm running systemctl daemon-reload and systemctl restart project.service to rerun it.

@ElJay: You should be able to debug it by doing env - PATH=/bin:/usr/bin /bin/bash -c "set -x ; . ~/.bashrc ; exec /home/user/.local/share/pnpm/pnpm start" ; I can't make progress because my node is in /usr/bin.

That command gives this output: `. /home/user/.bashrc
++ case $- in
++ return

exec /home/user/.local/share/pnpm/pnpm start


project@0.1.0 start /home/user/project
node .

sh: 1: node: not found
 ELIFECYCLE  Command failed.`

In case this is relevant information, my node command is in the same folder as the pnpm command. (/home/user/.local/share/pnpm/node)

@ElJay: Ok; it's pretty obvious the problem is you have a messed-up .bashrc. That return statement is causing the rest of it to not run.

The comment above it says "If not running interactively, don't do anything". Should I just delete that part? Would it have any other unintended consequences? Or would there be something I can do to meet it's condition?

@ElJay: Oh that makes it easy then. Move the path modifying code from the bottom of .bashrc to the top. It's a lot easier than trying to understand the whole through a narrow view.
